# Connecting phpMyAdmin to MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I want to be able to create EER-diagram to handle relationships between my tables. I found MySQL Workbench and installed it on my PC. I wonder if I can import my tables to the program from phpMyAdmin, and how do I do that if it´s possible?

Or even better, can I connect phpMyAdmin to MySQL Workbench so that I can manage everything from Workbench, such as creating new tables, editing data in tables and stuff like that?

Comment: Why don't you just reverse engineer the schema for the db from the workbench directly?? Why the need for phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Nupul means why don't you connect Workbench directly to the database? You probably have to configure the remote server where MySQL runs to allow remote connections, through SSH (and tunnel MySQL connection) or allow direct connections to MySQL (through the typical port 3306).

Comment: @ypercube I´m note sure I´m allowed to use other clients than phpMyAdmin, I´m hiring my web space at one.com.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin is just a web page. The Web Server is usually in the same machine as the MySQL one he can directly connect through port 3306 to it. Check if you can set SSH access. I don't think it's possible to connect Workbench to MySQL through PHPMyadmin.

Answer (score -3):

I don't think you can create a direct 'link' - but you can export from phpMyAdmin in SQL format (it's in the 'export' tab when overviewing the selected database) - and then import this into MySQL Workbench.

It is then possible to reverse the process to export changes from MySQL Workbench and import them back into the database through phpMyAdmin.

If doing this you would need to either include 'drop table' instructions in order to replace tables completely with any changes you have made to their structure, or think about how to alter existing tables in the SQL.

If you use 'drop table' you will lose any data stored in the table.

I find this quite useful at original design stage for the database, but less use once there is data in the system - although it continues to be useful as a way of visualising changes made using phpMyAdmin.